# Is it possible to see a list of executing functions in Visual Studio while debugging without breaking?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, callstack

I've worked with the **Call Stack**, **Call Hierarchy**, and **Profiler**. None of these tools gives me a simple, *live* "just executed function list"... in a tool Visual Studio window. I need something to look at when I click a button or link that guides me to a specific code file and line (if available).

I've found nothing of the sort. Maybe, even if PDB FULL is on, such information isn't available. I believe at this point that I'll have to write a Visual Studio 2012 Add-In or Extension to do what I need, but I run into problems there as well: For one, I can't get a function name from any [viable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb145585.aspx) unless I pause the debugger or encounter a break-point. Second, the application that I want the list for is a MVC app that runs as a DLL under "WebDev.WebServer40.exe".

I thought this would be very simple: From an extension, create a tool window and log the last executed method along with argument list.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!!

EDIT: For additional clarity

Comment: Are you looking for a list of which functions were hit to review after execution, or a point in time snapshot of what thread is in which function? In the first case you should persist with the profiler, but configure which functions are of interest. For the second the thread view in Process Explorer (not in visual studio) may help

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for "_a list of which functions were hit to review after execution_". But I'd like the list to be live. A specific example is this: I hit F5 to start debugging a MVC Web Application and every time I click a link the MVC Class.Method that was called gets printed.

Comment: It sounds like your particular problem might be better solved by using dependency injection with the MVC framework to inject your own wrapper interface that logs calls to the MVC framework objects.

Comment: Windows development, is hell. All the tools you NEED, aren't there. Thank god people pay for microsoft products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio Ultimate, you can use [IntelliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336126.aspx). Alternatively, you can try [Runtime Flow](http://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/), but it can't work at the same time with VS debugger.

Comment: I think your answer is the best for the moment. I'll persist in my endeavour for a "live functions list". Also, thank you for your Favorite Documents extension!